# move object with timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have an object with a diagonal movement in a form, the initial position is the center, i want to stop the movement when the object is on the corner of the form an return the movement to the initial position, thanks for the help, I have the first movement but i don't now how i can return.

```
public void functionThread()
{
   var timer2 = new Timer();
   timer2.Interval = 50;
   timer2.Enabled = true;

   timer2.Tick += (s, e) => panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 5, panel1.Location.Y - 5);
}
```

Comment: Firstly make sure you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  Hard to tell from your exammple

Comment: Threading.Timer can be declared like that.

Comment: WPF already has [animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx). In its simplest form, you can specify that an element's property will vary from one value to another over a range of time. In its most complex, you can specify storyboards of multiple transitions

Comment: @EpicKip which is exactly my point.  You shouldn't be using `Threading.Timer` on the UI thread for a WinForms app

Comment: @MickyD I mean the way his code is, it can't be Threading.Timer

Comment: BTW, if you want to perform animations, don't use WinForms. Changing coordinates through a timer results a high CPU load, jerky motion and slow updates. Performance can be very bad if there are a lot of elements on a screen that have to be redrawn.

Comment: Note that Timers have their own thread. Your code looks like it is spawning the timer on a separate thread, which is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This code makes the panel go from left to right, its starting position is 10,10 (`BasePoint`) and it will set back the panel once it hits the edge so it can go again. You can also stop the timer once you hit this bool, only change then would be to declare the timer globally, this answer is provided by: [Nino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42804332/2885376)

```
bool HitEdge = false;
Point BasePoint = new Point(10,10);
Timer timer2 = new Timer();

public void functionThread()
{ 
    timer2.Interval = 50;
    timer2.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((panel1.Left + panel1.Width) >= this.Width)
    {
        HitEdge = true;
    }
    if (!HitEdge )
    {
        panel1.Left += 15;
    }
    else
    {
        panel1.Location = BasePoint;
        HitEdge = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is correct solution and it could be useful to OP (or, in fact, it could be the solution OP was asking for). So the downvote isn't needed.

Comment: The form won't dispose that timer since it wasn't declared at the form scope.

Comment: @LarsTech Happy? :)

Answer (score 1):

Move `timer2` declaration out of your function and put into form, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
    }
```

in your `functionThread` make method for `Tick` event, to make code easier to read and maintain

```
timer2.Tick += Timer2_Tick;
```

In `Timer2_Tick` method check for panel's location and stop timer if necessary

```
private void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Left == 0 || panel1.Top == 0)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
    }
    else
        panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X - 5, panel1.Location.Y - 5);
}
```

Comment: He had to return to starting location, never said the timer had to stop

Comment: @EpicKip _"i want to stop the movement"_  - that implies the timer should stop so as to be nice to the OS.  It's a question of efficiency

Comment: @MickyD "return the movement to the initial position"

Comment: @EpicKip So you like having a timer running just for the sake of it?

Comment: @MickyD If I return the movement to the initial position it sounds to me like you want to make it move again from there. That's why. Else it shouldn't be "return the movement"

Comment: if OP wants additional explanation or some other change or improvement od given code sample, I will gladly change my answer and provide further explanations or code changes. Insisting on not stopping timer looks like nitpicking to me. If you don't think this aswer is useful, feel free to downvote it.

Comment: @Nino I just noted something, I do not insist on anything. I provided an example of the other side of it (which was downvoted although it does detect when the edge is reached and how to set the basepoint...). I won't downvote you either because your answer is fine, but Micky was insistent on discussing with me